# Vue: Add items to computed property results which do not exist my Array of Objects

Tags: vue.js

I have a computed property that filters the results on the date:

```
resultfilteredResults() {
      const filteredResults = this.results.filter((result) => {
        return Date.now() < new Date(result.metaData.E);
      });
      return filteredResults;
    },
```

That works fine.

Now I have realized that my filteredResults need to contain data that does not necessarily exist in the specific Object.

For example. One bit of data within the object in the Array looks like this:

"C": "Pakistan, Vietnam, Wales, Western Sahara, Yemen, Zambia"

Sometimes "C" will not exist (when this is the case it means it should bring back all available data in all "C" objects within the whole Array. This is because it is not only for specific counties but all countries. I hope that makes sense.

I tried this but it does not work.

```
 resultfilteredResults() {
      const undefinedResults = result.metaData;
      {
        const filteredResults = this.results.filter((result) => {
          return Date.now() < new Date(result.metaData.E);
        });
        if (undefinedResults == "undefined") {
          return undefinedResults;
        } else {
          return filteredResults;
        }
      }
    },
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: in you html template you can run new fetchData function when the data is not available. and after that your "this.results" will be filled and your computed method will auto update.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code.

What is not clear is `if (undefinedResults == "undefined") {`

`undefinedResult` is a string `"undefined"`? or just `undefined`?

Can you try this?
`if (undefinedResults == undefined) {`

Comment: Thanks both for helping. You are correct of course. It should be this: if (undefinedResults == undefined). It's still not working though. I get this in the console: [Vue warn]: Property or method "result" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

Comment: Thanks!  Its really too long to share but here is one of the computed properties for one of the select menus.  I have had to split it in 2 as the character limit in comments is exceeded. Can you from this? 

uniqueSubjects() {
      //this first bit switches between results and results filtered depending on whether 'Show Closed' is checked
      const metaVFees = (this.ClassCheck === true
        ? this.results
        : this.resultfilteredResults
      )

Comment: .filter((result) => result.metaData && result.metaData.V)
        .map((item) => item.metaData.V)
        .filter((subject, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(subject) === i);
      // Split multiple subjects in strings and store in an array
      let subjects = [];
      metaVFees.forEach((item) => {
        const splitArr = item.split(", ");
        subjects = subjects.concat(splitArr);
      });
      return subjects
        .sort()
        .filter((subjects, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(subjects) === i);
    },

Comment: The error indicates that your template refers to `result`, but that should probably be `resultfilteredResults` to match the computed prop name.

Comment: I think your template uses 'result' which is not defined in data or computed property.
resultfilteredResults can't let vue know result is defined as computed property